# Donut Chart with labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, label, donut-chart

I'd like to create a donut chart that is labeled. The labels themselves should be outside of the graph and connected via lines to the according part of the donut chart. Here is what I've come up so far, but I struggle to create the lines and prevent the labels from overlapping.

**# Data Frame**

```
geschlecht <- as.data.frame(tibble(
  gender = as.factor(c("männlich", "weiblich", "nicht-binär", "keine Angabe")),
  count = c(46, 43, 7, 4)
))
```

**# Calculate percentages**

```
geschlecht <- geschlecht %>% mutate(fraction = count / sum(count),
                    ymax = cumsum(fraction),
                    ymin = c(0, head(ymax, n=-1)),
                    labelPosition = (ymax + ymin)/2,
                    label = paste0(gender,"\n",count, "%"))
```

**# Create donut chart**

```
    geschlecht_donut <- ggplot(geschlecht, aes(ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin, xmax=4, xmin=3, fill=gender)) +
  geom_rect() +
  geom_label( x=3.5, aes(y=labelPosition, label=label), size=6) +
  coord_polar(theta="y") +
  xlim(c(2, 4)) +
  
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "OrRd") +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme_void() +
  guides(
    fill = "none")

geschlecht_donut
```

Here is a picture of the current output and the output I'd like to have.

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mwaq4.jpg)

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vov6Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to switch to `ggrepel::geom_label_repel`, place the labels on the border using `x=4` and add some nudging. I also added some curvature to the segments connecting the labels to the data points:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

ggplot(geschlecht, aes(fill = gender)) +
  geom_rect(aes(ymax = ymax, ymin = ymin, xmax = 4, xmin = 3)) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(x = 4, y = labelPosition, label = label),
    size = 6, hjust = .5,
    nudge_x = 1, direction = "x",
    segment.curvature = -0.1,
    segment.ncp = 3,
    segment.angle = 20, seed = 123
  ) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y", clip = "off") +
  xlim(c(2, 5)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "OrRd") +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme_void() +
  guides(
    fill = "none"
  )
```

[image]